# On the Evolution of Random Graph (Existence of Log-size Components)

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, random-graphs

**Theorem:**  Let $ \mathbf c > 0, p \geq \frac{c}{n}.$ Prove that there exists $a>0$ such that with asymptotical probability 1, the size of the largest component of $G(n,p)$ is at least $a\ln n$.

**What I tried:** By Cayley's formula I know that there are exactly $k^{k-2}$ spanning trees on $k$ vertices. And let $X_k = $ number of tree components of size $k$ in the graph $G(n,p)$. And the Expectation can be expressd as: $$E(X_k) = \binom{n}{k} k^{k-2}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{k(n-k)} \approx \frac{n^k e^k}{\sqrt{2\pi k}k^k}k^{k-1}(1-\frac{c}{n})^{k(n-k)} \approx \frac{n e^k c^{k-1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}k^{2.5}}(1-\frac{c}{n})^{kn} \approx \frac{n(e^{1-c}c)^k}{\sqrt{2\pi}k^{2.5}}$$

But I am stuck here. How do I prove this theorem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean $0\leq c<1$?

Comment: @SumanChakraborty Yes

Comment: You can look at this simple proof here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6529.pdf (Theorem 1 part 1).

Comment: @SumanChakraborty That's an upper bound, not a lower bound.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Correct, my bad!

Comment: If I am now understanding your problem correctly, then look at Theorem 1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610466.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the kind assistance and recommendations dear **Suman Chakraborty** and **Misha Lavrov.** **Here is my complete attempt. Please help me with the evaluation**

By Cayley's Formula we know that there are exactly $k^{k-2}$ spanning trees on $k$ vertices. let $p=\frac{c}{n}$
Let $X_k =$ number of tree components of size $k$ in a graph $G(n,p)$ and let $k = a \ln n$
$$ E(X_k) = \binom{n}{k} k^{k-2} p^{k-1} (1-p)^{k(n-k)} \backsim \frac{n^k e^k}{\sqrt{2 \pi k}k^k} k^{k-2} {\backsim{c}{n}}^{k-1} \left( 1-\frac{c}{n} \right)^{k(n-k)} $$
$$ \backsim \frac{ne^k c^{k-1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}k^{2.5}} \left( 1 - \frac{c}{n} \right)^{kn}  \backsim \frac{ne^k c^{k-1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}k^{2.5}}e^{kn \left( \frac{-c}{n} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^2}) \right)} \backsim  \frac{ne^k c^{k-1}e^{-ck}}{\sqrt{2\pi}k^{2.5}} \backsim  \frac{ne^{(1-c)k} c^k}{\sqrt{2\pi}ck^{2.5}}$$
Let us simplify the numerator
$$ \hspace{0.2cm} Let \hspace{0.2cm} (e^{1-c}c)^k \geq \frac{1}{n} \implies n \geq (\frac{1}{n} e^{c-1})^k \implies \ln n \geq k \ln (\frac{1}{c}e^{c-1})^k $$
$$ \ln n \geq k \ln (\ln \frac{1}{c} + x-1) \implies k \leq \frac{1}{\ln \frac{1}{c} + c-1} \ln n \implies k \leq a\ln n $$ $$ \therefore EX_k \rightarrow \infty, k = a\ln n $$
It remains to compute the variance
$$ Var X_k = EX_k + EX_k (X-1) - (EX-k)^2$$ $$ EX_k(X_k - 1) = \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{k}k^{2(k+2)}p^{2(k-1)} \left(1-p \right)^{2(\binom{k}{2} - k +1)} \left( 1-p \right)^{2k(n-k)}\left( 1-p \right)^{k^2} $$
We can see that $$ EX_k(X_k -1) \backsim (EX_k)^2 \implies Var X_k = \mathcal{O} ((EX_k)^2) $$ Applying Chebychev's inequality we get:
$$ P(X_k =0) \leq \frac{VarX_k}{(EX_k)^2} = \circ (1) $$